# How to make PHP categories like a CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just started to learn PHP and i'm trying to make a basic cms, the problem is that I don't know how to make the url `mysite.com/cat1` show the articles of the category 1, I usualy use `mysite.com?cat=cat1` then:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat']))
{
  $articles=mysql_query("select * from articles where cat=".$_GET['cat']);
}
else
{
  $articles=mysql_query("select * from articles");
}
```

But I think that `mysite.com/cat1` would be better and more secure, also I'm using `$_GET` for the pages.

Comment: You have to use .htaccess RewriteRule

Comment: @DmytroDzyubak Please make a full answer.

Comment: It's not more secure to use those url's instead of just GET params. It's nicer though.

Answer (score 2):

create `.htaccess` file at `mysite.com/.htaccess`

The contents of `.htaccess` file should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cat([0-9]+)$ /cat$1.php [L]
```

the contents of `mysite.com/file.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['cat']))
{
  echo $_GET['cat'];
}
else
{
  echo "GET is not set";
}
?>
```

Now, if you follow `mysite.com/cat1` the output would be:

```
1
```

It also works for `mysite.com/cat123`, etc.

Reference:

[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) (see "Figure 1" in "Regex Back-Reference Availability" section)